# Query last data of different documents in Azure Cosmos db (SQL)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Sample data :

```
{age: 20, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 20, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 30, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 30, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 40, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 40, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 40, ts: '00:02'}
```

Expected output:

```
[{age: 20, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 30, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 40, ts: '00:02'}]
```

Tried

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.age in (20, 30, 40) order by c.ts desc
```

But the result selected all data.

Comment: you need to write nested query to to find Max(ts) please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440920/get-latest-id-from-a-duplicate-records-in-a-table

Comment: @silentsudo the OP is about Cosmos DB SQL API while the link you provided is for SQL Database.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS, would SQL syntax be the same?

Comment: @June7...No. Please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started.

Comment: approach will be same syntax will vary :/

Comment: @silentsudo...That's correct. I realized it the hard way :).

Comment: @silentsudo nested query is not a good way to implement low RUs especially the data is huge ..

Comment: yes, agreed, in the link i post an exact solution what you posted is present.

Comment: @silentsudo Thanks for your help , I might have not described my sample data clearly . What actually result I need is if the condition matched and I want to select * ( all properties of the document) to be the output but select some of them . Since my sample has been solved , but I couldn't solve my real problem . Just wondering whether you could help me or not at this point. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like the following:

```
SELECT max(c.ts) as ts, c.age FROM c where c.age in (20, 30, 40) 
Group By c.age
```

This gives the following output:

```
[
    {
        "ts": "00:02",
        "age": 40
    },
    {
        "ts": "00:01",
        "age": 30
    },
    {
        "ts": "00:01",
        "age": 20
    }
]
```

Comment: What if the original data has hundreds of properties ? Is there a way to select data including all properties ?

Comment: I don’t know. Based on the details you provided, I came up with this solution. You may want to edit your question and include more details.

Comment: @FVBn - you can specify `*` instead of discrete properties. Really your choice.

Comment: @DavidMakogon But it will lose max(c.ts) or any way you could provide ?

Answer (score 1):

(ONLY APPLIES IF IT IS A LOT OF DATA)

I would not work with queries too complex in CosmosDb, beware of the RUs that can spike very fast (and your monthly bill as well).

The bad part is that your question does not show your context (is this for a UI, for a report...).

I would recommend perhaps using Cosmos triggers to generate this data persistently.

```
AgesDetail (current table)
{age: 20, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 20, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 30, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 30, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 40, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 40, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 40, ts: '00:02'}
```

When a record is replaced or added, to update a new table

```
AgesMax
{id: 20, ts: '00:01'},
{id: 30, ts: '00:01'},
{di: 40, ts: '00:02'}
```

This would improve your reading time, and definitely lower your RUs.

You can also apply this on your code layer to send a message down a queue to pickup and transform the data.

Either way, the recommendation still holds I think. Separate your readings from your real table to get better performance and be more cost-effective.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I could only resolve this question by forloop in my code.

Comment: Context is : I have multiple partitions(data) in my cosmosdb. I'd like to query the last one of each partition that were uploaded at the latest time.