# Query last document with all properties of different data in the same collection with Cosmos db SQL API

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

#### This is the extension of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527835/query-last-data-of-different-documents-in-azure-cosmos-db-sql?noredirect=1#comment110583712_62527835)

#### Question:

How to select the last document of different data with all property.

The difference from the Link is I need to take the data object along with the document being selected . But I found it would select all document from if `group by c.data` as well

#### Sample Data:

```
{age: 20, data: {...}, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 20, data: {...}, ts: '00:01'},

{age: 30, data: {...}, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 30, data: {...}, ts: '00:01'},

{age: 40, data: {...}, ts: '00:00'},
{age: 40, data: {...}, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 40, data: {...}, ts: '00:02'}
```

#### Expected Output:

```
[{age: 20, data: {...}, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 30, data: {...}, ts: '00:01'},
{age: 40, data: {...}, ts: '00:02'}]
```